# Unable to get records using Django ORM

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, orm

**Problem:**

Trying to get a record using Django ORM, from a table that contains a JSON field, I'm using the following line:

```
test_object = House.objects.get(id=301)
```

**Error**

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

**Possible issue**

Noticed that a previous developer updated the format of the JSON field in the table, seems that JSON had a bad format. Script used to format the JSON column:

```
 for i in data:
 jsonstring = json.dumps(i.result)
 new_clear = jsonstring.replace("\\", "")
 new_clear = jsonstring.replace("NaN", "null")
 i.result = json.loads(new_clear)
 i.save()
```

**Comments**

In pgAdmin the JSON field looks good and it is formatted properly, see a partial copy of the JSON below:

```
{"owner_id": 45897, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "DNC", "estate_id": 3201, "sale_date": "3/18/19", "property_street": "123 main st", "property_city": "Miami", "property_state": "FL", "property_zipcode": 33125, "Input_First_Name": "John", "Input_Last_Name": "DNC"}
```

I would like to know how to deal with this JSON field in order to query the object. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check the type of json_data. If it's already a dict then don't json decode...

Comment: Hi, I'm just querying from the shell using a get like this one: House.objects.get(id=301). I'm not running any custom logic, just want to get the object. Thanks

Comment: You are passing a dictionary to a function that expects a string

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a custom decoder being used in the field ([docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField.decoder)).
If the json data is valid in db, try connecting to db in shell using `psycopg2.connect()`, query, and decode using `json.loads()`.
I'd intended to post this as a comment, but not enough reputation, in case this is of any concern.